# Подскажите простой, хороший компилятор для изучения Си

Tags: c

Подскажите какую лучше использовать среду разработки(IDE) для изучения Си новичку, на которой будут работать примеры из книжек

Comment: побуду К.О, но как по мне, то для начала самое оно - онлайн компилятор. И попробовать можно, и побаловаться. http://ideone.com - есть подсветка синтаксиса, можно скомпилировать и запустить одним нажатием. http://codepad.org - совсем блокнот. Но рабочий. http://melpon.org/wandbox/ - недавно нашел. Плюс - можно установить локально.

Comment: @KoVadim у этих редакторов трудно с CodeInsight и прочими технологиями автодополнения. А без них трудно давать содержательные имена сущностям и появляется соблазн обозвать переменные a, b, c, d

Comment: Боюсь, меня затюкают :), но посмотрите в сторону Open Watcom - прост, как швабра, для начинающего, как по мне, самое оно. Хотя всякие "C для чайников" обычно пользуют Code::Blocks. Не поверите - но лично я для чего-то не особо крупного использую очень древний редактор FTE с настройками "под себя" и компиляцию в командной строке...

Comment: @gbg `CodeInsight и прочими технологиями автодополнения` - для мелких программ по первым главам книг с/с++ это все не нужно и только мешает.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я так прозреваю, что вы ищите IDE.

Ставьте Qt Creator + GCC. Галочку о скачивании самой Qt можно сбросить.

Почему не:

- Visual Studio? Потащит за собой .NET и прочее добро
- Dev CPP или Code::Blocks? Глючные и визуально страшные велосипеды.

Comment: висуал студио самое лучшее по моему для этого

Comment: .NET и так в винде скорее всего есть, не так ли? С Visual Studio вообще ничего не сравнится, просто лучшая IDE, ради нее можно и потащить .NET, даже если его нет. В защиту Code::Blocks – велосипед не более глючный и не более визуально страшный, чем Qt Creator (ну это вообще субъективно). И дополню список еще – есть неплохой CodeLite.

Comment: "Потащит за собой .NET и прочее добро" - куда потащит, извините?

Comment: @gdb `простой компилятор = плохой компилятор` . Не согласен. Для изучения только языка програмирования, достаточно только компилятора. Вы же предлагаете изучать компилятор и библиотеку Qt. А это в два раза сложнее , особено когда не знаещь ньюансы языка. В Qt применяются такие механизмы , новичок голову сломает сразу . притом Qt это С++.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian посмотрите, сколько гигабайт вытягивает инсталлятор студии, и сколько, инсталлятор QtCreator, если скачивать его без самой Qt.

Comment: @Yaroslav, во первых, я не отладчик. Во вторых, сам Qt я даже не предлагаю скачивать. В третьих, изучать C++ без IDE - это из той же серии, что носить шубу мехом вовнутрь и сидеть в ящике с гвоздями.

Comment: @gbg Думаю вам надо бежать из такой команды, где для жизненного необходимых инструментов не находится несколько гигабайт трафика.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а если ТС получает интернет через 3G?

Comment: @gdb Да сам начинал изучать C++ в Borland 3.1. В IDE. )))

Comment: @Yaroslav ДА НЕ ОТЛАДЧИК Я. Посмотрите на мой ник.

Comment: @gdg Так я тоже между строк читать не умею, тока предположения.

Comment: а пункт про Dev CPP или Code::Blocks я не понял... чего в них такого страшного? По мне так лучше в них писать чем в блокноте каком-нибудь.

Comment: @pavel я долгое время работал и с той и с другой. QtCreator кажется более "доделанным".

Answer (score 3):

GCC + любой текстовый редактор (хоть Блокнот), для новичка вполне сойдет SublimeText. Разберетесь не только в языке, но и в том, как программы компилировать руками через консоль, мейкфайлы научитесь писать, отлаживать программы через консоль.

Почему не IDE? Я особого смысла не вижу. Писать задачи из K&R вполне можно и в Блокноте, собираются они все равно одной строкой в консоли. Единственная достойная IDE – Visual Studio, но под линукс его нет, так что пришлось пользоваться Sublim'ом, потом пересел за Emacs и таки сделал себе IDE по вкусу.

Comment: Под linux вполне работоспособны Qt Creator и CLion.

Comment: Qt Creator не люблю, CLion платный же вроде? Вообще с продуктами JetBrains у меня не сложилось после установки PyCharm на винду и лицезрения загрузки дольше, чем ОС.

Comment: @Flowneee: Это вы зря, современная Windows грузится очень шустро. (Говорит, конечно, не в пользу PyCharm.)